# Counting unique values in multiple columns/dimensions with d3.js/crossfilter.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I have a table of quiz results. It's imported as an array of objects in which every object represents a collection of one user's answers.
It has a property that holds the **unique user id** and multiple properties with his answers (~25). The key of every of these properties is the **question id** and the value is the **answer id**.

What is the best way to count unique values (answers) in every column (for every question) for building a kind of histogram, considering that all this values should be updated swiftly every time some filter is applied to the dataset.
*For example, we decided to display only the data for the users who gave a specific answer to one of the questions. So all other summaries should be generated only for this specific group of users.*

Every possible approach (like iterating every time though all of my objects and their properties or creating 25+ dimensions in Crossfilter) seems ugly. Is there any rational solution of this, or should I rather use some other data structure? Any advice on data structure optimisation will be gladly received. Thanks.

Example of data:

```
user_id,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,32,33,34,35
10168,0,0,6,3,1,6,0,0,4,1,2,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
10654,2,0,6,3,3,1,3,0,0,0,3,3,0,-1,1,-1,2,2,3,5,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
11110,2,0,6,1,1,6,0,0,1,1,3,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
11392,6,0,6,1,2,1,1,3,2,0,3,1,0,-1,1,-1,8,8,3,4,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
11484,2,6,1,5,0,6,0,0,4,1,3,1,0,-1,1,-1,7,8,3,0,-1,-1,1,0,1,1
```

Same data in it's *long* form. Seems irrational to use because the file size is 4 times larger.

```
id,ques_id,value
10168,7,0
10168,35,-1
10168,34,-1
10168,33,-1
10168,32,-1
```

Comment: With the long form, you can use `d3.nest()` to nest by question. This would give you the values you need for the histogram.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks, using it now. So far it's the best solution that I found.